# Quantum Gravity

Tags: gravity

By the Pauli exclusion principle fermions cannot occupy the same space, cannot have identical quantum numbers. The bosons however can. We also know that the universe, and in particular the various states of energy are driven by conservation laws. So, during the big bang, a singularity, something happened and fields were created, which created very stable particles, fermions, stable enough to span out, by repelling each other (Pauli) and "stretch" the spacetime continuum, i.e. we can see the expansion even today.

So, if not for the existence of fermions, spacetime would contract back the natural state of a singularity. Hence, is it to outrageous to say that it the "global" influence of the strong nuclear forces that keep the fermions intact, on spacetime that shape it. And the gravitational law gives us the geometry of this effect.

If it is this stretching of spacetime that manifest as an attractive force of fermions then it could be proven by observation, hopefully the JWST will some day give us enough data, in that we will see that the universe has no edges because spacetime will curl in on itself as the gravitational field weakens in any void of low baryonic matter. In essence the "edges" of the universe is vacuum voids with nothing but fields permeating through them.

Comment: I don't think that the big bang is the *simplest* singularity.

Comment: I have no idea what you are actually asking, and there are several claims in here which are either speculative or simply false.

Comment: please reword the title of this question to something that sums up the body in one complete sentence. It should be a clear descriptor, not a generic heading.

Comment: *The bosons however can because the have no mass.* - No, it is because they have integer spin.

Answer (score 1):

> The bosons however can because the have no mass.

There are massive bosons, too. $Z_0, W_\pm,$ Cooper pairs, etc.

> So, by the conservation laws the spacetime would tend to the singularity again if not for the stable fermions.

That sounds a bit speculative. We're tending towards the singularity again depending on whether or not space is going to eventually contract, which depends much more keenly on things like the cosmological constant which you'd not generally associate with fermions. If you just had a universe of noninteracting photons it would be very boring and there would be little point to doing anything but following the worldlines out to infinity, but it would not obviously be a *big crunch* universe.